# Kivy SoundLoader makes Python unresponsive

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on creating a mobile app with Kivy and tried to add beeps to indicate workout progressions. I've made a small (39kb) .mp3 file containing 1 beep. I've added these to the same folder as my main file and use the following code with the Kivy SoundLoader. Here is the minimal reproducible code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_start(self):
        print("Started")
        self.one_beep = SoundLoader.load('countdown-1 second.mp3')
        print("Finished!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

The issue is that this makes my app unresponsive for 5+ minutes while this piece of code runs ("Starting" is printed and no error message). After that the app finishes loading, becomes responsive again and playing the beep does work. I've tried loading the sound upon starting the app and later when I needed the beeps but at both points my app has 'crashed'. I've also tried to create a non-class variable for the sounds and I tried the same sounds in .wav format. The file does play on Windows Media Player. I have Googled and searched an answer on this site but the problem doesn't show anywhere else. Does anyone know how to speed up the loading, because this makes my app unusable.I've now also tried threading as suggested below but the app crashes in the same manner (before the rest is executed):

```
def start(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.load_sound())
    t.deamon = True
    t.start()
    self.calculate()
    self.create_workout_list()
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.update,1)

def load_sound(self):
    print("Started")
    self.one_beep = SoundLoader.load('countdown-1 second.mp3')
    self.three_beep = SoundLoader.load('countdown-3 seconds.mp3')
    print("Finished!")
```

I've uploaded the sound here: `https://sndup.net/37vm`

Comment: How big are those `.mp3` files? You could try running the `Soundloader.load()` in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanking you for taking time to look at my problem. The filesizes were in my original post (39kb and 176 kb). I never worked with soundloader before but I don't think that the size should be this hard to load. I've tried your suggestion to create a seperate thread but the app crashes similiarly and the code after creating the thread doesn't run. I've updated my original post and added the threading code.

Comment: Change `target=self.load_sound()` to `target=self.load_sound` , without parens.

Comment: Unfortunatly same results, it does start running. It prints "Started" but still freezes immediatly afterwards

Comment: It may have something to do with `self.calculate()` or `self.create_workout_list()`. You should post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, I was able to reproduce the issue with just the soundloader line. I also uploaded the sound on other media  (Soundcloud) and there the sound does play.

Comment: I found the solution! I uninstalled kivy-deps.angle and kivy-deps.glew which did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! I uninstalled kivy-deps.angle and kivy-deps.glew which did the trick for an unknown reason.