# Kivy UI freezes while loading audio with SoundLoader

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am trying to use background audio and sound effects that can be triggered by events or UI actions in my Kivy application. However, I am struggling to find a way to load the audio files without the process freezing the UI.

In the below examples, the "backgroundsound.ogg" is an audio file with size ~2MB, and causes the app to freeze for ~5 sec. on my test Android phone (running Android 12).

(In the actual app, I'm loading this and similar tiny files for sound effects and already causing ~20 seconds freeze.)

Any pointers or suggestions would be much appreciated.

**(1) A basic example:**

When built and run on Android, this would take approx 5 seconds on presplash screen then goes black for about 5 seconds (while loading the audio), only then the UI appears. When pressed, it plays the sound as expected.

```
kv_string = '''
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Play sound"
            on_press: app.submit()
'''


from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

# load sound
sound = SoundLoader.load('backgroundsound.ogg')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    # play sound
    def submit(self):
        sound.play()

MainApp().run()
```

**(2) Using threads**

Looking for solutions, I only found a few references to the problem, like [Kivy SoundLoader makes Python unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718134/kivy-soundloader-makes-python-unresponsive), with the suggestion always referring to using separate threads.

After some reading and learning about threading, I tried a few different ways, with the aim of ideally having some background process loading the audio files into GLOBAL variables, so they can be called and played by different triggers from the app UI. For example:

```
kv_string = '''
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Play sound"
            on_press: app.submit()
'''


from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import threading

# parameter indication if sound is available or not
sound_loaded = False
# placeholder for loaded sound
sound = ''

# function to load sound and overwrite the parameter when done
def load_sound():
    global sound 
    global sound_loaded
    sound = SoundLoader.load('backgroundsound.ogg')
    sound_loaded = True
    print('sound loaded')

# initiate the sound loading thread
sound_load_thread = threading.Thread(target=load_sound)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    # play sound if loaded, else do nothing
    def submit(self):
        if sound_loaded == True:
            sound.play()
        else:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = MainApp()
    # start the sound loading thread
    sound_load_thread.start()
    # start the app 
    app.run()
```

- this however doesn't seem to help and results in identical behaviour, i.e. presplash (~5 sec.) > black screen (~5 sec.) > app loaded and plays sound when button pressed

**(3) Narrowing the problem down**

Below code was modified to test 2 hypotheses:

1. Hypothesis 1: the whole new thread is freezing the UI

   - Test: adding time.sleep(N) to see if the App is unresponsive for the duration of sleep
   - Result: False. With the below code, app loads (without black screen) and button is responsive until the SoundLoader line, when it freezes for ~5 sec.
2. Hypothesis 2: the reason the UI freezes is that the new thread is loading the sound into a global variable ( impacting the main thread)

   - Test: do not load into global variable, instead, load and play the audio locally
   - Result: False. With the new code, the app still freezes during the SoundLoader action

```
kv_string = '''
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            font_size: 32
            text: "Play sound"
            on_press: app.submit()
'''
    
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import threading
import time

# function to load sound 
def load_sound():
    # do something to delay the sound loading
    # UI is responsive during this time
    for i in range(6):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
    # continue to loading the sound
    print('loading sound')
    # UI is not responsive while the load runs!!!
    SoundLoader.load('backgroundsound.ogg').play()
    print('sound loaded')
    
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    # function assigned to the button to test UI responsivness
    def submit(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = MainApp()
    # start the sound loading thread
    threading.Thread(target=load_sound).start()
    # start the app
    app.run()
```

I also tried using this https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application as a starting code, but as soon as I add SoundLoader into the function called by the thread, the same behaviour occurs and UI is not responsive during the audio load.